# Dynamically remove iptables policy by IP address

Tags: iptables, bash

I would like to remove some NAT POSTROUTING rules in an automated fashion based on the source or destination IP address.

I know the source and destination IP but I don't necessarily know which policies are already there.

For example, I may have this:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/32 -j ACCEPT
```

or I may just have this:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/32 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

I want to unassign that NAT address from the old computer and assign it to a new computer. This is all automated so I can't manually look for it.

What's the best way to remove the old polices for just that IP? Could I use a list + grep command? I normally hang out in the Windows world so I'm not sure the best way to handle this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match a rule for deletion by specifying it precisely and using `-D` (`--delete`) instead of `-A`. For instance:

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

To script this, matching a specific IP address, and not losing any rules due to race conditions, let's try something like this. This will delete any rule in the nat table containing a given IP address:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for rule in `iptables-save -t nat | grep -w $IP_ADDRESS | sed -e 's/-A/-D/'`; do
    echo $rule | xargs iptables -t nat
done
```

Some notes on this: We use `grep -w` to ensure that IP addresses match exactly, and e.g. a given address that ends in `25` doesn't match `250`. The transform from `-A` to `-D` is done by `sed` in the loop. And we use `xargs` to expand each rule into parameters.

Comment: That is it exactly! I also had to add IFS=$'\n'; to the beginning, I assume because my command shell default splits by spaces instead of line breaks. I do have the risk of race conditions so that and being fast make this the perfect solution.

Comment: You're quite right about IFS. I knew that and completely forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING -n --line-numbers | grep -w 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $1}'`

That would grep IP that you want and grab the line number of the firewall rule. Then use `iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1` to delete rule 1, or whatever number you want.

Comment: That looks perfect. I just need to learn the syntax to auto-generate the command using awk so that I can actually carry out the delete in the same command. Your example actually gets the rule numbers which is just what I need. I'm heading into a meeting but I'll research that next.

Comment: This approach has a race condition: if any firewall rules get added or removed between the time you `grep` and the time you delete, you end up deleting the wrong rules.

Comment: `iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING BACKTICKiptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING -n --line-numbers | grep -w 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $1}'BACKTICK`

That would do it all in one command, assuming the comment markup didn't destroy it. But Michael Hampton's approach is probably still the more correct method.

EDIT: The comment markup did get in the way. Replace BACKTICK with actual backticks in the above command.